# Django diferrent value of DateTimeField at created/updated

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, mysql-python

I would like to store time of created and modified. But when I use below model:

```
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
date_update_local = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

`auto_now_add` does't work properly. If I created object at first time, everything is ok, I have properly value of `date_created`, but if I modify exist object then `date_created` is set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000`.

So I modified my code as below:

Models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_update_local = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            p = Product.objects.get(reference=self.reference)
            self.date_created = p.date_created
        except self.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Views.py

```
p = Product(reference = 'no. ref')
p.save()
```

I am checking does object exist, if True, I am get last `date_created` value and set it as new value. But I think it is wrong solution.

Comment: can u show us the full image of views.py... have u defined a model form?

Comment: I left code at office. This is almost the whole views.py, before is only `def Import Prod ():`. I have not defined form.